# Python: extract text from tag inside tag in XML Tree

Tags: python, xml, tags, extract

I am currently parsing a Wikipedia dump, trying to extract some useful information. The parsing takes place in XML, and I want to extract only the text / content for each page. Now I'm wondering how you can find all text inside a tag that is inside another tag. I searched for similar questions, but only found the ones having problems with a singular tag. Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
  <revision>
    <timestamp>2001-01-15T13:15:00Z</timestamp>
    <contributor>
      <username>Foobar</username>
      <id>65536</id>
    </contributor>
    <comment>I have just one thing to say!</comment>
    <text>A bunch of [[text]] here.</text>
    <minor />
  </revision>

  <example_tag>
    <timestamp>2001-01-15T13:15:00Z</timestamp>
    <contributor>
      <username>Foobar</username>
      <id>65536</id>
    </contributor>
    <comment>I have just one thing to say!</comment>
    <text>A bunch of [[text]] here.</text>
    <minor />
  </example_tag>
```

How can I extract the text inside the text tag, but only when it is included in the revision tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`xml.etree.elementtree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) package for that and use an XPath query:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(the_xml_string)
for content in root.findall('.//revision/othertag'):
    # ... process content, for instance
    print(content.text)
```

(where `the_xml_string` is a string containing the XML code).

Or obtain a list of the text elements with list comprehension:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

texts = [content.text for content in ET.fromstring(the_xml_string).findall('.//revision/othertag')]
```

So the `.text` has the inner text. Note that you will have to replace `othertag` with the tag (for instance `text`). If that tag can be *arbitrary* deep in the `revision` tag, you should use `.//revision//othertag` as XPath query.